# frm-92100:your connection to the server was interrupted

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, windows-server

**frm-92100:** error I use my using internet explorer & JInitiator 1.3.1.13 using oracle 11g and dev9i windows server 2008 R2. The app was running fine for last 2 years but suddenly this happen.

I have tried and read almost every page i found from google search but it doesn't help me.

what I tried 
I set `NLS_LANG` to a valid value like `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256` in the `default.env` file which is being used. then it not allow me to login anymore. Also try to set it on environment/registry the result is same.

Only the login form is not loading but all other form run manually from my app.

[image]
Please help me.

Comment: Did you check your 'jdk' and 'jre' are same version or not .

Comment: sometime jdk is auto updated and the latest one JRE was not being picked up by the Forms Applet.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan thanks for your answer but I am using JInitiator so how to what is the matter of JRE

Comment: I think you didn' went thoroughly to all answer matter. could you again go through. kindly check out the 2 pints onwards the answer matter.

Comment: Jinitiator is a Java virtual machine (JVM) made and distributed by Oracle Corporation. Jinitiator 1.3.1.25 is based upon JDK 1.3 or later. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinitiator

Comment: it seems there is no solution just only the error

Comment: Did you try the below mention steps.

Comment: Yes I did those steps

Comment: ,There is also 'Frm-92100 Error Oracle' repair tool. But strongly i would not suggest to do that. http://winbytes.org/wiki/windows_errors.php?kw=Frm-92100%20Error%20Oracle#4. To repair the Frm-92100 Error.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Thanks for your help. it might not work

Answer (score 0):

As you said you did try with both option

```
 1. Set NLS_LANG to a valid value like AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256 in
    the default.env file or any custom environment file which is being
    used.    

 2. You can go to regedit and also set the NLS_LANG value to the one
        mentioned above and check if this resolves the issue.
```

As per `ABBASGOL'S BLOG` [FRM-92100 : your connection to the server was interrupted](https://abbasgol.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/frm-92100-your-connection-to-the-server-was-interrupted/) If the Above Solution Doesn’t Work For you Try The Below One :

```
1) FRM-92100 occurs when invoking a new forms session from existing form session, or another URL is invoked from the parent browser window of the forms applet?

To work-around use the applet parameter separateFrame=”True”. This parameter is set in the static html file or formsweb.cfg
2) If using Oracle Jinitiator, try clearing the Jinitiator JAR or jcache:

For versions 1.3.x.x.x : Control Panel – Jinitiator Control Panel – Cache Tab Page – Clear JAR Cache button

3) If using MS Internet Explorer check that permissions / security options are set correctly

Launch Microsoft Internet Explorer.
Select the Tools -> Internet Options from the top level menu.
Click the SECURITY Tab:
Choose Local Intranet Zone from the list.
Click Custom Level.
Select Java Permissions – Custom from the list.
Click Java Custom Settings.
Select the Edit Permissions tab.
Choose Enable for Run Unsigned Content.
Choose Enable for Run Signed Content.
Select the ADVANCED tab.
Scroll down to Java VM.
Check the Java console enabled option.
Select the CONNECTIONS tab.
Click the LAN Settings button.
If IE is using a proxy server : Check the Bypass proxy server for local addresses check box. Click the Advanced button, and enter the local domain in the Exceptions box. Use the form *.domain.com, where domain.com maps to your local domain.
Click OK to exit the dialog.
Click OK to save the changes and exit IE.
Restart the computer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Este error "frm-92100 your connection to the server was interrupted", me dio porque tenia un "Item mostrado" y quería colocar un texto usando ch(10), es decir, instrucciones como este tipo, son las que también ocasionan este error. Le quite el ch(10) y funciono, esto en la version Oracle Forms 10.1.2.0.2

(Translated w/ Google Translate):

This error "frm-92100 your connection to the server was interrupted", it gave me because it had an "Item displayed" and I wanted to place a text using ch (10), that is, instructions like this type, are the ones that also cause this error . I removed the ch (10) and it worked, this in the Oracle Forms version 10.1.2.0.2